# Rails 5, master branch, use generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For somes test, i want to try rails 5 alpha and use the generator.

I just create a new application ( `rails new test` )

I change the gemfile and add/replace :

```
gem 'rails', github: "rails/rails"
gem 'arel', github: 'rails/arel'
```

And i get this error :

```
~/c/test ❯❯❯ rails g model Model table_name:string model_name:string indexes:hstore
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 9 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/user/codes/test/.gems:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/gemsets/global:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0', execut
e `gem env` for more information
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
        from /Users/user/codes/test/.gems/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

How can i install the railties for rails 5 ?

Comment: This question is outdates as of Dec 18th 2015 when Rails 5.0 beta was released.  For those looking to use 5.0 as of now, create a gemset and use
$ gem install rails --pre

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you follow these steps...

```
git clone https://github.com/rails/rails.git
cd rails/
bundle install
cd ../
./rails/railties/exe/rails new myapp --edge --dev
```

...then cd into myapp folder you should see...

```
ruby-2.2.2 marklocklear:myRails5App marklocklear$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.0.alpha
```

Note the `--edge` and `--dev` options when creating the app should set the Gemfile pointing to the right place.

Comment: Worked for me. However, not on first try. Had to separately `gem install mysql -v '2.9.1'` and then `bundle install` a second time. Thanks.

Comment: I had to also do `rake install` in rails directory for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

## Way to go for Rails > 6.1

Rails 6.1 added a new command-line option `--main` to use the rails `main` branch as the source.
NOTE: `--master` option is now an alias of `--main`.

Now, you can use the following command:

```bash
rails new test --main
```

Generated Gemfile:

```rb
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below gem list into your Gemfile -

```
gem 'rails', github: "rails/rails"

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem "jquery-rails"
gem 'turbolinks', github: 'rails/turbolinks'
```

this will ready to go for Rails 5, turobolinks 3 and add pg if you wants to use postgresql as DB backend or else.

see nicer implementation of [todo list in Rails 5](https://github.com/nateberkopec/todomvc-turbolinks)